# Partial derevatives of multi variables

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

[image]

Hi I don't understand this problem.

$F$ is a function of $r$, right?

I can find the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial r}{\partial y}$, and $\frac{\partial r}{\partial z}$. Now what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the chain rule: $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$.  Note that $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \frac{x}{r}$ and the same goes for the other coordinates.  We have that

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial^2F}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2F}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2F}{\partial z^2} & = &  \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left ( \frac{x}{r} \frac{\partial F}{\partial r} \right ) + \frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left ( \frac{y}{r} \frac{\partial F}{\partial r} \right ) +  \frac{\partial }{\partial z}\left ( \frac{z}{r} \frac{\partial F}{\partial r} \right ) \\
& = & \left (\frac{1}{r} - \frac{x^2}{r^3} \right )G(r) + \frac{x^2}{r^2} G'(r)  + \ldots \\
& = & 0.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: df/dr is g(r) right? I think im missing the big picture. I have no sense of direction as to how to proceed this question and why we need to find df/dx in the first place.

Comment: @RStyle Take a look at some of my edits.  This should hopefully give you an idea of where to start.

Comment: Hi thanks. Could you explain how you differentiated d/dx (x/r  * df/dr) into (1/r - x^2 ......).. Is it product rule?

Comment: @RStyle It is the product rule.  Note that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{x}{r} = \frac{1}{r} - \frac{x}{r^2}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$.